# CLLocation manager Gives me old position

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

i used CLLoction manager to get location.but when ever i start my location then it gives me oldlocation which is store in device previously.i want to reset the location for this i used flag on first launch of application i used newlocation and call stopupdateinglocation and startupdatinglocation method.But oldlocation is not changed it show old location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every `CLLocation` has a `timestamp` property that you can use to filter all location updates that are too old for your usage.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSTimeInterval age = [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if(age < SOME_CONSTANT_IN_SECONDS)
    {
        //Use location
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant able to get the old location in the swift code of above method. is there any methods to get the old location?

Answer (score 0):

You can't clear the old location, but you can check the horizontalAccuracy to know if this is a good location (current) or something old and irrelevant.

Comment: oldlocation means if i start my application and GPS gets Coordination and after walk of 5KM i start my application once again and GPS oldlocation is previous location. i calculate distance in my application it show 5KM move but i start my application and not moved.